# Is it possible to delete one of my accounts after they were merged?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts, merge-accounts

My two different accounts were merged into a single one. So, I would like to delete one of the accounts. Is this possible? If yes, then how can I do this and is there any consequence to this on deleting one of the accounts that was merged?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one account is merged with another, the merging account (not the target) will be deleted as part of the process.

Comment: but still it is showing another id into the account with which it is merged and can swap to that id also

Comment: @Nikki Do you have the two user ids?

Comment: yes wrongly i have created one of my own id and another is by default of gmail id

Answer (score 0):

Email us directly at the address provided at the bottom of every web page we serve.